# Removing Virtual Inheritance

Tags: c++

I am working on an embedded project I am trying to remove a virtual number class that has + / - * implemented. removing this class saves a lot of code space so I have replaced + with the following function,

```
if (BASE(h)->type() == FLOAT && BASE(v)->type() == FLOAT)
{
    res = FLOAT(h)->floatValue() + FLOAT(v)->floatValue();
}
else if (BASE(h)->type() == INTEGER && BASE(v)->type() == INTEGER)
{
    res = INTEGER(h)->intValue() + INTEGER(v)->intValue();
}
else if (BASE(h)->type() == INTEGER && BASE(v)->type() == FLOAT)
{
    res = INTEGER(h)->floatValue() + FLOAT(v)->floatValue();
}
else 
{
    res = FLOAT(h)->floatValue() + INTEGER(v)->floatValue();
}
```

Is there a less uglier way to achieve this? cause I have to use the same scheme for other ops and comparison?

Comment: [You probably mean polymorphism, not virtual inheritance.] Why did you replace the good solution with the broken one, then ask how to fix the broken one?

Comment: because as I said I am out of flash space (32k) this saves around 4k which is alot plus saves ram (no extra pointer due to virtual base)

Comment: @Hamza: You did not say that at all.

Comment: Please don't use `<code>` or `<pre>` tags. That's what the code formatting button is for (indent by 4 spaces).

Comment: @Tomalak: I think `removing this class saves a lot of code space` qualifies as `because as I said I am out of flash space`. At least in my understanding of the words.

Comment: Is `floatValue()` a C++ `float`/`double` or an object? If it's an object why are you calling it for example with `FLOAT(h)->floatValue()`? Can the result be different than `h`? What is the type of `res`?

Comment: @6502, floatValue returns a c++ float, FLOAT macro casts a base pointer into a Float object.

Comment: Then why not the much simpler `float res = float_value(h) + float_value(v);` by adding the utility function `float float_value(void *p) { return BASE(p)->type() == FLOAT ? FLOAT(p)->floatValue() : INTEGER(p)->floatValue(); }` ?

Comment: because res is not a float for all cases int + int = int not a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define GETFLOAT(arg) (BASE(arg)->type() == INTEGER ? INTEGER(arg)->floatValue() : FLOAT(arg)->floatValue())

switch(BASE(h)->type()) {
    case INTEGER:
        if (BASE(v)->type() == INTEGER) {
            res = INTEGER(h)->intValue() + INTEGER(v)->intValue();
            break;
        }
    case FLOAT:
        res = GETFLOAT(h) + GETFLOAT(v);
}
```

This actually branches on the type of `h` twice, but only in the case that (you say in a comment elsewhere) is expensive anyway, the floating-point op. You could avoid that with a `goto`, but I'm not going to have that argument again. Something like:

```
switch(BASE(h)->type()) {
    case INTEGER:
        if (BASE(v)->type() == INTEGER) {
            res = INTEGER(h)->intValue() + INTEGER(v)->intValue();
            goto finished; // or better: return res;
        }
        hvalue = INTEGER(h)->floatValue()
        break;
    case FLOAT:
        hvalue = FLOAT(h)->floatValue();
}
res = hvalue + GETFLOAT(v);
finished:
```

As with Howard's answer, if `BASE()` or `type()` is expensive then you could calculate the answer for each argument once, even though it's used twice.

Answer (score 2):

What about doing it in two steps?

```
isInt1 = BASE(h)->type()==INTEGER;
isInt2 = BASE(v)->type()==INTEGER;

if (isInt1 && isInt2)
  op1 = INTEGER(h)->intValue();
  op2 = INTEGER(h)->intValue();
  res = op1 + op2;
else {
  op1 = isInt1 ? (FLOAT(h)->floatValue()) : (INTEGER(h)->floatValue());
  op2 = isInt2 ? (FLOAT(v)->floatValue()) : (INTEGER(v)->floatValue());
  res = op1 + op2;
}
```

Comment: with this int + int results in float which is really expensive on MCU

Comment: @Hamza ok, that was too fast then (was misled by your code `FLOAT(?)->intValue()`. shouldn't that by `INTEGER(?)->intValue()`). In that case you may only separate INT/INT as special case.

Comment: my bad messed up during copy paste, when both are in result is int

Comment: @Hamza see my edit for one possible solution (although it is more complex - don't know which is more applicable in your case). You will not get less than two operations since one of them is always INTEGER+ while the other one is FLOAT+.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reconsidering your architecture. How much have you saved with this approach, and how much has it cost in performance? Your new approach appears pushes everything to a float (you didn't show the declaration of `res`, which I presume is `float res;`.

Examine what this fix does to something like `(a+b)*c`, where each of a, b, and c are (were) integers. With this fix at hand, you now have a float times an int, which is a lot more expensive computationally than an int times an int.

I suggest using templates and letting C++ type system handle as much of the conversion as possible. This lets you use disparate storage types that don't have to have common virtual base class.

You can also cut down on program size by implementing only one of int+float versus float+int (and similarly with int*float versus float*int). Temporarily implement both int+float and float+int, but intentionally make one raise a compile-time error. Flip the order of the operands where you get failures.

Comment: there was a mistake I made int + int is int everything else is float so I am not pushing everything to float, res is of type Base not a primitive. plus this 1/8 saves of flash memory.